# java cloning sqlite database files

Tags: java, sqlite, clone

My app loads a database file, say myDatabase.db, into in-memory data structures, i.e., various Java class objects. The user does inserts, deletes and edits on the the in-memory structures. I'm trying to decide what is the best way to save these changes back to a disk file.

I can either (a) do the corresponding inserts, deletes, & updates at the same time as the internal data structures are changed, thus keeping myDatabase.db always in sync, (b) somehow stack up the changes and defer changes to myDatabase.db at the end of the session.

One advantage of (b) is it would allow a final "Do you want to save these changes?" before committing. Implementing (a) appears to be easier but I would like to offer the user the opportunity to abandon the changes.

Which brings me to the question: what's the best way to clone the database upon loading? If I can do that I can use (a) making changes to the clone, then use it to overwrite myDatabase.db if the user wishes.

TIA

Ed S

Comment: The answer highly depends on the total DB size (number of records) and percent of changed data.

Comment: It's pretty small. Largest table is about 500 records with typical address, phone numbers etc. In all, there are 15 table, all smaller.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use transactions - you may begin a transaction, then translate all the changes "online", and then when the user agrees to save data, the application simply perform commit (or rollback)

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work with the GUIs I've implemented. In the main GUI there are command menus such as Add Entry and Delete Entry which each launches it's own GUI. These command GUIs allow for multiple Adds or Deletes, and the work is done by the action code invoked by the button click. A Finished button closes the form and the user is back at the main GUI. It would seem that I would have to ask the user if he/she wants all the Adds just entered to be saved, even though the user might want to do more Adds, Deletes, Edits, etc. Where would the Commit go?

Comment: I guess what I'm wondering about is if the Commit can be done in a function other than the one where the Begin Transaction was set up.

Comment: No, I've proposed a bit different solution. The regular workflow should assume immediate actions: additions, removal etc. And these actions are directly translated to the DB, being wrapped into a single "global transaction".

Comment: The whole process is similar to the implementation of some (if not most) text editors when edits performed by a user are applied immediately, but never saved into the destination file, until the user clicks 'Save' button. Instead the editor stores the edits into a special (hidden) file right beside the file being edited, and then "commits" them when the user presses 'Save'. This approach allows to restore state of the edited but not saved file if e.g. the editor crashes in the middle of the process. Check e.g. [vim](http://vim.org).

Comment: I'm not following you. You say "wrapped into a single "global transaction"" what do you mean exactly? Perhaps PreparedStatements & AddBatch/ExecuteBatch?

Comment: I do want it to work like a text editor though. That's why I'm thinking about cloning the initial database, doing the transactions on the clone, then saving it if the user confirms with an explicit Save.

Comment: OK, I think I've got it. I put the Prepared Statement as a global variable in the GUI dialog class, the set and addBatch statements in the Add action handler, and the executeBatch in the Save action handler. It works in a small example. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: [Transactions](https://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html) are completely independent of prepared statements. [The former](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) are the method of keep DB consistent and fault-tolerant, while [the latter](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) are the method to perform the changes, speed them up etc